# How do I get the first max distinct element in a list?

Tags: python

```
    populations = [[0 1]
                   [1 1]
                   [0 1]
                   [0 1]]
```

`score = [0, 6, 4, 4]`
`best_score = max(score)`

What I want to do is to get `chromosome_best` by first, matching
`best_score` with `score` and get the index that match in `score`, then using this index, get its corresponding value in `populations`

My code so far looks like this:

`chromosome_best = numpy.array([d for a, d in zip(score, populations) if a == best_score])`

But how could I change it such that when score has non-unique values, example:
`score = [6, 6, 0, 4]`
`best_score = 6`

The `chromosome_best` that would be read is the first match between `score` and `best_score?`

Answer (score 2):

Something like `populations[score.index(best_score)]` should do the trick. [`list.index`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp) returns the first index where the list matches the element you provide, therefore it will always match with the first occurrence, no matter how many there are

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippets should give the first match.

```
next(d for a, d in zip(score, populations) if a == best_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` with a key function:

```
chromosome_best, best_score = max(zip(populations, score), key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

So we zip them together and `max` determines the maximum of tuples `zip` gives by looking at their element at `1`st index i.e. the score. We unpack the result to get best chromosome (and also best score). `max` gives the first maximum value encountered among all, so we get the desired result.

This solution traverses the lists only once.